# Image Gallery with database and explode function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, database

I am trying to create an image gallery where there would be one big image on top and a selection of thumbnail images at the bottom. Let me reference the last question I have here.

[Image Gallery Using php css and javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46520079/image-gallery-using-php-css-and-javascript)

So I edited the code above and added explode function, and MySQL database. Since I have more than 1 image gallery on one page (due to  categories). i had stored the image names in this format (reception.jpg?reception2.jpg?reception3.jpg) this is stored under the img column in myphpadmin. However, when I tried to apply the changes, it seems both the php/html together with the css code worked fine. but it also seems that it is not able to read the **script** tag that i placed on the most bottom part of the page. JS code contains the same code as the link above. Do you know where I had it wrong? it was able to read the rest. and hover effects work. it's just that, it is not selecting the thumbnail image upon clicking. I tried remaking it on a different page and it works fine for as long as the **script** tag is within the **head** tag

here is the revision I made

```
<?php 
                        $gallery = $value['img'];
                        $gallery = explode("?", $gallery); 

                        if(!empty($gallery)) { ?>
                        <div class="eight-eight" id="gHolder">
                                <div class="eight-eight" id="theBigImageHolder">
                                    <img src="includes/images/<?php echo $gallery[0]; ?>" id="bigImage">
                                </div>
                                <div class="eight-eight" id="thumbnailsHolder">
                                    <?php foreach($gallery as $key => $item){ ?>
                                        <img src="includes/images/<?php echo $item; ?>">
                                    <?php } ?>
                                </div> 
                            </div>
                            <?php } ?>
```

here is the complete code incase anyone would be asking

```
require_once 'includes/templates/header.php';
require_once 'core/connection.php';
$facility = new Facility;
$facilities = $facility->all();
?>
<!-- General Public View -->
    <div class="container">
        <?php include_once 'includes/templates/banner.php'; ?>
        <div class="full">
            <span class="eight-eight">
                <?php include_once 'includes/templates/nav.php'; ?>
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="full">
            <h1 id="catchphrase">Facilities</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="full facilities">
            <?php
                foreach ($facilities as $key => $value) { ?>
                    <span class="four-eight grid">
                        <h2><?php echo $value['name'];?></h2>
                        <!---Start Image Gallery -->
                        <?php 
                        $gallery = $value['img'];
                        $gallery = explode("?", $gallery); 

                        if(!empty($gallery)) { ?>
                        <div class="eight-eight" id="gHolder">
                                <div class="eight-eight" id="theBigImageHolder">
                                    <img src="includes/images/<?php echo $gallery[0]; ?>" id="bigImage">
                                </div>
                                <div class="eight-eight" id="thumbnailsHolder">
                                    <?php foreach($gallery as $key => $item){ ?>
                                        <img src="includes/images/<?php echo $item; ?>">
                                    <?php } ?>
                                </div> 
                            </div>
                            <?php } ?>
                            <!---End Image Gallery -->
                        <p class="eight-eight"><?php echo $value['description'];?></p>
                    </span>
                <?php }
            ?>
        </div>
        <?php include_once 'includes/templates/footer.php'; ?>
    </div>
<?php }

?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var doi = '2015/10/15';
    $('#clock').countdown(doi, function(event) {
    $(this).html(event.strftime('%D Days %H:%M:%S')); });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
      function imgFunc(){
          var bigImage = document.getElementById("bigImage");
          var thumbnailsHolder = document.getElementById("thumbnailsHolder");

          thumbnailsHolder.addEventListener("click",function(event){
            if (event.target.tagName == "IMG") {
              bigImage.src = event.target.src;
            }
          }, false);
      }
      window.addEventListener("load",imgFunc,false);
  </script>
```

Comment: start to debug the problem check `console.log()` from previous example https://jsfiddle.net/okhsvet0/1/ is showing proper `src`

Comment: @DeepakKumar I'm sorry but how do i do that?

Comment: if you are using chrome browser hit F12 developer tools will open and you can see console tab. there you can see `src` check in my fiddle first and then try in your code

Comment: @DeepakKumar oh that, I already did that earlier but no error comes out

Comment: just an update. i tried to see which part is it not working and upon test. it goes to the javascript but i doesn't proceed to this code >>>> thumbnailsHolder.addEventListener("click",function(event){
            if (event.target.tagName == "IMG") {
              bigImage.src = event.target.src;
            }
          }, false);

Comment: so finally script is not working. So put the script just after `<p class="eight-eight"><?php echo $value['description'];?></p></span>` and before `<?php } ?>`

Comment: i tried that but same error. it won't switch images. I also tried placing the script in a separate js and calling it out// adding the head tag above and pasting the script on the head tag//adding the script in the header.php (because i separate my header file and footer to the body/content. still all the same error

Comment: another update, I tried creating a different form. but i noticed that its not reading all the javacript commands at all. would there be a cause to that?